# Possible to add new class to existing dll and update it to the source file

Tags: c#, .net

```
  Collection of C# class source code file, with Microsoft.Csharp.CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters,ClassFiles) we can create an assembly dll file.

       public static string[] sourcefiles = new string[]{
                    @"D:\pro1bk\projects\WCFService.cs" ,           
                    @"D:\pro1bk\projects\Calculator.cs"            
                                 };

 public Assembly Compile()
     {
        CSharpCodeProvider provider;
        CompilerParameters parameters;
        CompilerResults results;

        parameters = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters();

        AddAssemblyReference(
            typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute).Assembly,
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies);

        AddAssemblyReference(typeof(System.Xml.XmlElement).Assembly,
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies);

                 ........

                 ........
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = @"D:\pro1bk\ServiceCal.dll";
        parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
        parameters.WarningLevel = 4;
        parameters.TempFiles.KeepFiles = false;

        if (TargetFramework == TargetFramework.Silverlight)
        {
            parameters.CompilerOptions = " /nostdlib ";

        }

        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(DefaultReferencedAssemblies);
        //parameters.MainClass = "App";
        try
        {
            provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, sourcefiles);
            results.PathToAssembly = "";
            List<ErrorInfo> errors = new List<ErrorInfo>(results.Errors.Count);

             ......

             ......

          }

}
```

above code for create dll file.

I just copied that DLL (ex. ClientProx.dll) to another project. Now, I have a created new class with methods and how to add this new created class to the existing DLL (ex. ClientProx.dll) with old classes.

And after added the new class in that DLL (ex. ClientProx.dll), which should update in appropriate file as new class.

How can we do this at run time ? Is it possible add new class in existing DLL and update it to proper file location ?
Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the assembly would be **dangerous** and is not recommended!

Instead,

1>store the new compiled classes[dll] in the `Isolatedstorage` or in the folder you want!

2>Make a method that subscribes to the `AssemblyResolve` event.This method should now return unresolved dll demanded by the app from the `IsolatedStorage` or the folder.